# Manipulating occurrences of all letters in a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Desired functionality:

```
var myString = "123a4 1b234";
console.log(myString.allInstancesOfLetter().something();
//"123A4 1B234"
```

Is there a way to do this without having to complicate things with an array of all 26 letters etc.?

edit: toUpperCase() causing confusion, I didn't really think of that interaction, I was just choosing a random function.

Comment: What is `allInstancesOfLetter()` doing that `myString.toUpperCase()` isn't? It seems like we are missing an important part of what you are trying to do.

Comment: If your example is causing confusion then maybe consider changing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a callback function as second parameter when using the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method that will be applied to each ocurrence in a set RegExp.

```js
const myString = "123a4 1b234";
const result = myString.replace(/[a-z]/g, function(char) {
  return char.toUpperCase();
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

`toUpperCase` isnt applied to numbers, so

```
"123a4 1b234".toUpperCase()
```

works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

You just need `String.prototype.toUpperCase()`

```js
var myString = "123a4 1b234";

console.log(myString.toUpperCase());
```